# How to do a two select statement from a two table with a different datasets

Tags: php

Hello how can I do a two select statement with a two tables with a different datasets, and get their result? And how can I set the user_id that is from the another table?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_account WHERE NOT user_id= 'user_id'";

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM super_admin WHERE NOT id = '$admin_id'";
```

Table for users_acount.

```
user_id
user_fullname
user_email
password
facility
terms_and_conditions
isApproved
date
```

table for super_admin.

```
id
username
password
```

The process is the super_admin will appove the user, and in the logs it will show who is the admin that accepted that user.

Comment: Are you able to change your schema. The super user should be a user_type, not a table on its own.  The users table would have a foreign key to the user_table. The user_type table would have have eg: 1=>Super User, 2=>Admin, 3=>Moderator, 4=>Guest, and the users table would have a field called user_type_id which is a foreign key of the relevant user type.

Comment: I think, I can't.

Comment: Do you like to make a single for both tables?

Comment: @MainulHasan yes I would like to. How can I do it?

Comment: super_admin id is the same user_id of users_acount?

Comment: @MainulHasan no it is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user_group (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO user_group (name, password) VALUES('Super User', 'Complete Access');
INSERT INTO user_group (name, password) VALUES('Moderator', 'Limited Access');
INSERT INTO user_group (name, password) VALUES('Guest', 'Web Users');

CREATE TABLE users (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     user_group_id INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     FOREIGN KEY (user_group_id) REFERENCES user_group(id)
);
INSERT INTO users (name, password, user_group_id) VALUES('god', 'aaa666', 1);
INSERT INTO users (name, password, user_group_id) VALUES('davo', 'xyx123', 2);
INSERT INTO users (name, password, user_group_id) VALUES('prole', 'abc101', 3);
```